# Como chamar um método do CODEIGNITER numa view TWIG

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, twig

Bom estou iniciando a jornada num projeto, oferecido pela minha Escola, para ganhar experiência na área de programação, entrei no meio dele, e estou com alguns problemas de executar tarefas simples. Então estou tentando executar uma método, que depende de dados preenchidos na view, porém não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer tal ato.

**o Código a view:**

```
{% for post in posts %}
            <div class="ui card">
                <div class="content">
                    <span class="right floated star">
                        {{ post['data'] }}
                    </span>
                    <div class="header">{{ post['titulo']|e }}</div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>{{ post['descricao']|e }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="extra content">
                    <span class="left floated like" id="{{ post['id_post'] }}">
                        <i class="like icon"></i>
                        {{ post[''] }} Likes 
//AVISO AQUI EM CIMA É O LOCAL ONDE DEVERIA SER PREECHIDO COM A QUANTIDADE DE CURTIDAS //
                    </span>
                    <div class="right floated author">
                        <img class="ui avatar image" src="{{ post['caminho']|e }}"> {{ "%s %s"|format(post['nome'], post['ultimo_nome']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

**O método:**

```
 public function countCurtidas($idpost){
        return ($this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id_curtida) as curtidas FROM curtida WHERE id_post = $idpost")->row_array());
    }
```

Então para executar esse método preciso do `id_post` fornecido da view para logo em seguida já preencher com a quantidade de curtidas que esse post possui. Lembrando que a view é um template **TWIG** e estou usando o **CODEIGNITER**.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar o método countCurtidas dentro do método que busca pelos posts e carrega a view e passar esse número por pârametro para view assim como os posts, ou também pode realizar uma chamada ajax para o método countCurtidas, passando o id_post como pârametro.